# Removing duplicate copy of OneDrive in Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive

How can I remove the two copies of OneDrive in the File Explorer? I'd like to avoid registry hacks, as I don't want to brick my new laptop. It is a small bug and troublesome, but it's very annoying.

[image: duplicate OneDrive in File Explorer]

Comment: Can you clariy what you mean by, "I just cleaned it twice.", the statement is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to [other people](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odoptions-oddesktop/two-onedrive-entries-on-navigation-pane-after/aa678fa7-f62c-460c-8785-fbc8ebc92133). The answer there seems to be to convert the Microsoft Account to a local account and then convert back to Microsoft Account. The steps are:

> •Type Settings on the search box present on the Taskbar, then click on Account.
>   •On your account page, under the User name and User ID, you will be able to see "Disconnect" option.
>   •Click on Disconnect and follow the on-line instructions.
>
> Refer to these steps to convert Local User Account into Microsoft Account:
>   •Type Settings on the search box present on the Taskbar, then click on Account.
>   •Click on Connect to Microsoft Account and follow the online instructions.

Comment: Did not solve the problem. I tried it twice, local account to ms account. Still it has 2 onedrive. Maybe I got the latest build of windows 10 (not developers mode or beta) any tricks?